# Prove that there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|p(\theta)-\cos \theta|$ less than or equal to $10^{-6}$

Tags: proof-writing

I managed to prove until $|\cos x|$ less than or equal to $1$, but not sure how to continue, please help

Comment: Do you mean $|p(x)-cos(x)|$?  This is usually know as Theorem of Stone-Weierstraß, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: This is not true, as stated.  You would need a bounded domain for this to be possible.  In that case, a sufficiently high degree Taylor approximation would do the trick.

Comment: Another typo:  I assume you mean $|p(x) -\cos(x)|$?

Comment: Thanks! Edited the typo. How do I use the Taylor's Theorem to prove?

Comment: @omlette This isn't true as stated. There must be some restriction on $\theta$

Comment: How do I prove that it doesn't exist then?

Answer (score 0):

There is no polynommial $p$ such that, for all real numbers $\theta$, $|p(\theta) - \cos\theta|<10^{-6}$.

If the polynomial $p$ is not constant, then $\lim_{\theta \to \infty} |p(\theta)| = \infty$, so in particular $|p(\theta)|> 2$ for some theta, and thus $|p(\theta) - \cos\theta| > 1$.

If $p$ is constant, say $p(\theta) = c$ for all $\theta$,
then either $c\ge 0$ or $c < 0$.  In the first case, there exists $\theta$ so that $\cos\theta = -1$ and in the second case there exists $\theta$ so that $\cos\theta = 1$.  In both cases, $|p(\theta)-\cos\theta| \ge 1$.